# how to get all non matched part of text from a non-capturing group

Tags: javascript, regex

my regex is as follows

```
/({{(?:(?:(?:for|if|while):\w+)|(?:do))}})|(?:{{(?:fi|endfor|dowhile:\w+)}})/g
```

and my sample input is as follows

```
This is a sample {{if:val2}}abc{{fi}} injection{{while:val3}} {{endwhile}} string {{for:val}}repeated text{{endfor}} asdb lasdfk {{do}} basdf {{dowhile:val4}} asldf lkjasdf lajsdf aljsdf lkjasdf lasdf.
```

it got matched as follows

[image]

I want all the other non matched text as groups.

I can do this using the **RegExp.exec** and **lastIndex** value of the regex to create the groups using javascript.

But is there any way that I can achieve this using RegExp itself?

Comment: `s.split(/{{(?:(?:for|if|while):\w+|do)}}|{{(?:fi|endfor|dowhile:\w+)}}/)`?

Comment: Is there a reason for ignoring `{{endwhile}}`?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus just missed that. Thanks for bringing it to notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `String#split` after you convert all capturing groups in the pattern with non-capturing ones:

```
s.split(/{{(?:(?:for|if|while):\w+|do|endwhile)}}|{{(?:fi|endfor|dowhile:\w+)}}/)
```

If you keep a capturing group, it will be output together with matched parts.

JS demo:

```js
var s = 'This is a sample {{if:val2}}abc{{fi}} injection{{while:val3}} {{endwhile}} string {{for:val}}repeated text{{endfor}} asdb lasdfk {{do}} basdf {{dowhile:val4}} asldf lkjasdf lajsdf aljsdf lkjasdf lasdf.';
var rx = /{{(?:(?:for|if|while):\w+|do|endwhile)}}|{{(?:fi|endfor|dowhile:\w+)}}/;
console.log(
   s.split(rx)
)
// Getting rid of blank items and trim:
console.log(
   s.split(rx)
      .filter(function (x) { return x.trim() != ""; })
      .map(function (x) { return x.trim(); })
)
```